# Network manager icon suddenly disappeared along with internet connection

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, internet

I'm unable to access the internet on my laptop. On top of that, the network manager icon also went away all of a sudden.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

in the terminal run `nm-applet`. Network manager icon should come back again.

If did not work, try:
`dbus-launch nm-applet`

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't make the Network Manager icon come back.

Comment: Please check my answer again, I edited.